# Ubuntu 13.10 not detecting internal mic

Tags: sound

I just upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04, where my internal microphone worked fine.

However, I cannot get my internal mic to work now that I have upgraded. I use an Acer Aspire One 722 netbook.

This used to happen in older versions, but was easily fixed by turning the mic off and then back on. This time that isn't so.

Thank you!